# Non blocking socket - how to check if a connection was successful?

Tags: sockets, select, nonblocking

After setting up a non blocking socket correctly I do the following to connect:

1. Call connect on the socket.
2. If it returns 0, I have already connected, if not, check errno.
3. If `errno` is not `EINPROGRESS` there is an error.
4. if `errno` is `EINPROGRESS` I can poll the connect status by:

   `select_status = sock_select(FD_SETSIZE, NULL, &file_descriptor_set, NULL, &timeout);`

   if `select_status > 0` then check with `FD_ISSET` if the file descriptor is set.

Is that correct? And should I check for `fd_write` not `fd_read`? Should I call `getsockopt` after select? With what arguments?

I cannot find a clear explanation of what needs to be done.

I do connect but my program is not reporting it correctly so I am using `select` wrong or it is because I don't check `getsockopt`.

What tells me that the connection was made?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Call connect on the socket.
> 2. If it returns 0, I have already connected, if not, check errno.
> 3. If errno is not EINPROGRESS there is an error.

All of the above is correct (except under Windows you'd need to check for WSAEWOULDBLOCK instead of EINPROGRESS).

> 4. if errno is EINPROGRESS I can poll the connect status by: select_status = sock_select(FD_SETSIZE, NULL, &file_descriptor_set, NULL, &timeout); if select_status > 0 then check with FD_ISSET if the file descriptor is set.

Correct (assuming sock_select() is the same thing as select()), except that FD_SETSIZE should be the maximum value of all the file-descriptor values you are watching, plus 1.

> Is that correct? And should I check for fd_write not fd_read?

Right.

> What tells me that the connection was made?

When the async-connection-operation has completed, select() will return and FD_ISSET(theSocket, &writeSet) will return true.

When that happens, you need to find out if the connection attempt succeeded or failed.  Here's a function I use for that:

```
// Returns true if the async connection on (fd) is connected; false if it failed
bool DidTheAsyncTCPConnectionSucceed(int fd)
{
   struct sockaddr_in junk;
   socklen_t length = sizeof(junk);
   memset(&junk, 0, sizeof(junk));
   return (getpeername(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&junk, &length) == 0);
}
```

If that returns true, your socket is connected and ready to use in the normal ways.  If it returns false, the async-connection failed and you should close() the socket and handle that failure somehow.

(Again there is a slightly different behavior under Windows; under Windows, getting notified about the connection succeeding works as described above, but  if you want to be notified about the connection failing, you'll need to watch the exception-fd-set as well.  Under Windows, FD_ISSET(fd, &exceptionSet) is what will notify you when the asynchronous TCP connection failed).

Comment: Ty. The function DidTheAsync... works but select never returns > 0.

Comment: If select is returning 0, presumably your timeout has been reached before the TCP connection completed.  Try making the timeout longer, or removing the timeout.

Comment: DidTheAsyncTCPConnectionSucceed returns 1 when no connectionw as established as well...

Comment: sock_opt_result = getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, sock_opt_err, sock_opt_err_len); Then check sock_opt_err == 0, that seems to be the correct way here.