# SSL_connect for non blocking socket

Tags: select, openssl, nonblocking

I use a non blocking socket. For a normal TCP connect I do as in here:
[Non blocking socket - how to check if a connection was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481993/non-blocking-socket-how-to-check-if-a-connection-was-successful)

But for the SSL_connect call I cannot get it to work.

I understand it as I should:
1. Repeatedly call SSL_connect.
2. Check if SSL_get_error is SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.
3. If so, then I am not 100% sure what to do next. Should I call SSL_connect until I don't get that? Or should I do as with a normal socket, check the socket with select using read_fds or write_fds and check with FD_ISSET and if so check getsockopt with SO_ERROR?

Basically, for SSL_connect and a non-blocking socket, what tells me that the connection has succeeded? 
I have looked at other examples but none are clear enough.

Comment: Your guess is right: you should wait for appropriate socket events with `poll` or `select` api according to operation result. And repeat operation.

Comment: But should I call SSL_connect only once ever? What am I waiting for with select? if read or write is set for my socket, what does it mean? WHat should I do? Do I call getsockopt or not?

Comment: Usually you give a connected socket to `SSL_connect`. This function is not for lower-level connect operation, but for security protocol setup.

Comment: Yes I know. I can do SSL_connect with blocking sockets. But I am unsure about nonblocking ones. Some pseudocode for the whole process is what I need.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an algorithm:

```
int s = socket(...);
fcntl(s, ...); // make it non-blocking
while (-1 == connect(s,...))
{
   fd_set fds;
   FD_ZERO(&fds);
   FD_SET(s, &fds);
   select(s + 1, NULL, &fds, NULL, NULL);
}

... // initialize all SSL stuff
SSL_set_fd(ctx, s);
while (-1 == SSL_connect(ssl))
{
   fd_set fds;
   FD_ZERO(&fds);
   FD_SET(s, &fds);

   switch (SSL_get_error())
   {
   case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
       select(s + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
       break;
   case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
       select(s + 1, NULL, &fds, NULL, NULL);
       break;
   default: abort();
   }
}
// done...
```

Comment: Ty but I don't get the point of the select call. What does it achieve.? I stop on error or if SSL_connect != -1. What does the select call add?

Comment: `select` blocks execution until socket becomes readable or writeable. I.e. either there is a data in network buffer to read from remote peer, or available space in output buffer for sending.

Comment: I can't block, that is why I use nonblocking sockets. What I can do is call SSL_connect repeatedly and doing other stuff in between, is it possible to just call SSL_connect until it connects or there is an error? There is no point to the select call other than to wait?

Comment: You shall block whenever your event loop is empty. I.e. when it has nothing else to do. If you simply call function repeatedly you would overuse CPU resources. Or, if you can call it time to time it would also work in some way, but just produce extra kernel calls.

Comment: Ok, but just to be clear, all that is needed is a poll of SSL_connect until it succeeds or fails with another error than WANT_READ or WRITE?

Comment: SSL_connect() just incrementally processes through the connection workflow in the background. It reads or writes as much as is currently available, tells you whether it needs to write more or read more and defers to you to get the socket into that state, and then expects for you to call it again in order to go further the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example of an approach using non-blocking sockets with memory bios. The  non blocking IO is used to populate the memory BIO's, and IO calls are only made if the poll loop suggests they won't block.

https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca