# Handling 'Non-blocking' socket connects

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I am trying write a client that connects using non-blocking sockets, I am confused as to what I should check for and in which order.  I looked at [Non blocking socket - how to check if a connection was successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481993/non-blocking-socket-how-to-check-if-a-connection-was-successful) question and tried to implement it with no luck.  This is Windows, rather than Linux.  I would prefer to use the Posix methods so can I port it later.

The issue is that with Windows I am seeing EWOULDBLOCK even if the server doesn't exist. I am seeing multiple connections on the server once the server does appear, therefore I am not correctly handling the 'blocked' connection which hasn't completed yet.

The connect code is (and is called in a loop, if it can't connect straight away, until 100 tries or it connects):

```
bool IPV4Socket::Connect( std::string hostname
                        , unsigned short remotePort
                        , TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    AddrInfo getResults;
    AddrInfo getaddrinfoHints;
    int connReturn = 0;
    SockAddr_In *addrData;
    std::string service = std::to_string( remotePort );
    int errorCode = 0;

    getaddrinfoHints.ai_family = AddressFamily_inet;
    getaddrinfoHints.ai_socktype = SockType_stream;

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->getaddrinfo( hostname
                                     , service
                                     , &getaddrinfoHints
                                     , &getResults ) != 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    addrData = (SockAddr_In *)&( *getResults.ai_addr.begin() );

    connReturn = m_socketAdaptor->connect( m_socket
                                         , (const Sockaddr *)addrData
                                         , (int)getResults.ai_addrlen );

    static int staticLastErr = 0;
    static int staticConnStat = -2048;

    if ( connReturn == 0 )
    {
        m_isConnected = true;
        return true;
    }

    if (connReturn != staticConnStat)
    {
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] IPV4Socket::Connect() ::Connect() returned : " << connReturn << std::endl;
        staticConnStat = connReturn;
    }

    //  Check if the error is fatal - e.g. not blocking related!
    if ( connReturn == SocketError )
    {
        errorCode = m_socketAdaptor->GetLastError();

        //  Check for fatal connection error
#ifdef LIBSSL_OS_WIN32
        if ( errorCode != SockErr_EWOULDBLOCK )
#else
        if ( errorCode != SockErr_EINPROGRESS )
#endif
        {
            Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    SocketSet writeFDS;
    SocketSet exceptFDS;
    int selectReturn = 0;

    //  Clear all the socket FDS structures
    SocketSet_ZERO( &writeFDS );
    SocketSet_ZERO( &exceptFDS );

    //  Put the socket into the FDS structures
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &writeFDS );
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &exceptFDS );

    selectReturn = m_socketAdaptor->select( m_socket + 1
                                          , NULL
                                          , &writeFDS
                                          , &exceptFDS
                                          , timeout );

    //  select() failed or timed out, connection wasn't successful!
    if ( ( selectReturn == SocketError ) || ( selectReturn == 0) )
    {
        if ( selectReturn != 0 ) std::cout << "[DEBUG] m_socketAdaptor->select() returned : " << selectReturn << std::endl;
        Close();
        return false;
    }

    //  Check for error (exception) first
    if ( m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( m_socket, &exceptFDS ) )
    {
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] ::Connect() found excetion on 'm_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET'" << std::endl;
        Close();
        return false;
    }

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( m_socket, &writeFDS ) )
    {
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] ::Connect() m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( m_socket, &writeFDS )     [FOUND]" << std::endl;
        m_isConnected = true;
        return true;
    }

    Close();
    return false;
}
```

Close function:

```
int IPV4Socket::Close()
{
    int errNo = -1;

    if ( m_socket >= 0 )
    {
        errNo = m_socketAdaptor->shutdown(m_socket, ShutdownFlag_Both);
        if ( errNo < 0 )
        {
            int lastError = m_socketAdaptor->GetLastError();
            if ( lastError != SockErr_ENOTCONN && lastError != SockErr_EINVAL ) return lastError;
        }

        errNo = m_socketAdaptor->closesocket(m_socket);
        if (errNo < 0) return m_socketAdaptor->GetLastError();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Updated connect using comments:

```
bool IPV4Socket::Connect( std::string hostname
                        , unsigned short remotePort
                        , TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    bool connectReturn = false;

    if ( m_incompleteConnect == false )
    {
        connectReturn = PerformConnect(hostname, remotePort );
    }

    //  If connect failed (returned false) then abort!
    if ( connectReturn == false ) return false;

    //  If Connect() returned success, but didn't connect, it is because of a
    //  blocking IO not completing in time and needs to be retried, otherwise a
    //  connection was successful and just return success.
    if ( connectReturn && m_isConnected ) return true;

    m_incompleteConnect = true;

    fd_set writeFDS;
    fd_set exceptFDS;

    //  Clear all the socket FDS structures
    FD_ZERO( &writeFDS );
    FD_ZERO( &exceptFDS );

    //  Put the socket into the FDS structures
    FD_SET( m_socket, &writeFDS );
    FD_SET( m_socket, &exceptFDS );

    int selectReturn = ::select( m_socket + 1
                               , NULL
                               , &writeFDS
                               , &exceptFDS
                               , (const timeval *)timeout);

    //  Check if ::select() has timed out, if so, connection wasn't successful!
    if ( selectReturn == 0 )
    {
        m_incompleteConnect = false;
        return false;
    }

    if ( FD_ISSET( m_socket, &writeFDS ) )
    {
        m_isConnected = true;
        m_incompleteConnect = false;
    }

    //  Check for error (exception)
    if ( FD_ISSET( m_socket, &exceptFDS ) )
    {
        m_incompleteConnect = false;
        return false;
    }

    return m_isConnected;
}


bool IPV4Socket::PerformConnect( std::string hostname, int port )
{
    addrinfo *results;
    addrinfo hints;
    int connReturn = 0;
    std::string service = std::to_string( port );
    int errorCode = 0;
    bool returnValue = false;

    memset( &hints, 0, sizeof hints );
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if (::getaddrinfo( hostname.c_str(), service.c_str(), &hints, &results) != 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //  Attempt the connection...
    connReturn = ::connect( m_socket, results->ai_addr, results->ai_addrlen );

    //  If connect returned error (SOCKET_ERROR), check that it's not fatal -
    //  e.g. EWOULDBLOCK, if it is then connect can check until complete!
    if (connReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
        returnValue = (errorCode == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) ? true : false;
    }
    else
    {
        m_isConnected = true;
        returnValue = true;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: 'No luck' is not a problem description.

Comment: @EJP Added additional 'description' of problem.

Comment: You will always see EWOILDBLOCK first, whether the target exists or not. All that has happened after the `connect()` has returned is that a SYN has been queued for delivery. It is the following `select()` and error-checking that tells you whether the connect succeeded, failed, timed out, etc.

Comment: @EJP Thank you, what I don't understand is why the server-side is seeing multiple connections (e.g. 10-15), what made me think that the connect() isn't working correctly.

Comment: You aren't closing something.

Comment: @EJP I thought I covered all the bases with the Close().  I will add the Close() code to the main question.

Comment: @EJP - All returns have a Close() if fail, I added debug statements to check ::shutdown() and ::close() and they aren't failing, therefore I am totally stuck as to why it's behaving like it is... Any more suggestions?

Comment: You aren't closing something. That's the meaning of the error. You may think you're closing everything, but the error doesn't agree with you. One possible path is in the redundant part where you shutdown the connection before closing it: if there is an error from `shutdwn()`, you aren't closing the socket.  You don't need this. Just close it.

Comment: @EJP I changed it to m_socketAdaptor->closesocket( m_socket ); and still seeing the issue :(

Answer (score 2):

[connect from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (read return value carefully)

so the first time you try to connect in your loop, you get SOCKET_ERROR and errno=WSAEWOULDBLOCK; (this means everything is OK !!)

if you keep looping (connect again) you get SOCKET_ERROR and errno=WSAEINPROGRESS , so don't loop again !

so after getting WSAEWOULDBLOCK, as explained, you can,

> Use select to determine the completion of the connection request by checking if the socket is writeable.

```
fd_set wr_set;
struct timeval timeout={10,1};

int err=WSAConnect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,len,0,0,0,0);
printf("connect: %d %d\n",err,WSAGetLastError());


FD_ZERO(&wr_set);
FD_SET(s, &wr_set);

printf("%d\n",wr_set.fd_count);
select(s,0,&wr_set,0,&timeout); <- blocks (10s) only if can't get socket writable
printf("%d\n",wr_set.fd_count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `GetLastError` *immediately* after calling `connect`. All that code you have between those two functions can clear or change the error code.

Your code writes output to a stream between those two calls. If that write produces no error, the `GetLastError` won't get the error from the `connect` being in progress.

Move the `errorCode = m_socketAdaptor->GetLastError();` line to immediately after `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps anyhow but i found out that in the windows platform when you use the connect() function it will return a WSAEWOULDBLOCK(i think it is the same as EWOULDBLOCK). And you have to determine at a later time if the connection was actually successful or not.If you want you can check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (the section i refer to is that the "Return Value")

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately if you look at the code in the question I check for write-ability using select() and that hasn't helped unfortunately.

Comment: In which line of the code you have posted does the error occur? I mean the EWOULDBLOCK error.

Comment: I am not 100% where the failed close occurs.

Comment: Ok here is another thing(i haven't touched socket for some time so i might be wrong, i am just trying to help with whatever i am finding by googling). 

select() first parameter should be the max(writeFDs,exceptionFDs) + 1 - if you would use the read file descriptors you should get those into account as well - but in your case as the first parameter you pass the m_socket + 1 and as far as i can see the m_socket if the file descriptor acquired by the call to connect(). To be honest i don't think that this is causing the error but it wouldn't hurt to change it.

Comment: No difference, I wrote a small piece of test code and they return the same value - useful to be reminded about max though ;)

Comment: I am running Close() after every check, is there a check that I am missing maybe that could cause a fail?

Comment: To be honest yesterday i checked the project of yours at sourceforge to see if anything else would cause the issue but unfortunately i don't have the time to go through all the code. I've ran out of ideas to be honest.

Comment: Clutching at straws, but could issue be something to do with one or more of my wrapper functions?

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that with Windows I am seeing EWOULDBLOCK even if the server doesn't exist.

Since the socket is in non-blocking mode, also connect() returns immediately before actually having connected to the server. So getting EINPROGRESS is expected.

Without having the code for m_socketAdaptor, I can'reproduce this, but I am pretty sure the problem lies in this:

> The connect code is (and is called in a loop, if it can't connect straight away, until 100 tries or it connects):

If you already called connect() once and got (WSA)EINPROGRESS, you should not call connect again, but you should just be doing the select() part on the following iterations. Also you should not close() after checking once.

So what you should do is this:

- 1st pass - or if connect failed completely:

`getaddrinfo();
connect();
select();`

- 2nd-100th pass or until the select returns success:

`select()`

- If a previous call failed

`close()
go back to 1st step`

Comment: On windows, it appears you always get EINPROGRESS, regardless of if you have connected or not?

Comment: Correct. Not only on Windows, but on Linux, too. This is the expected non-blocking socket behavior. MS-Windows is correctly emulates traditional Berkeley socket API behavior for non-blocking sockets. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have modified my code (see question), but I am still seeing multiple connections... As if not correctly handling connect still

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Quick note : I have now changed my code to call the socket api directly.

Comment: The new code *seems* correct. Try putting a printf and a counter after the line where you call ::connect (or a breakpoint or log to a file). I believe that whenever you have multiple connections on the server side, that is because for some reason ::connect gets called multiple times.

Comment: @SamiSallinen - Connect() is continuously called and then hitting the line 'if ( selectReturn == 0 )' - I am assuming a timeout is a failure and treating it as, is that right?

Comment: I actually meant that you probably end up calling the winsock connect() api multiple times for some reason if you see multiple connections on the server side.

Comment: Typing in a hurry isn't my forte, I meant that ::connect() was being called numerous times because when doing the select on write & exception, if there was a timeout or exception the connection is closed.

Comment: I should gave read your new code more carefully.... When select times out, that is not an error, so dont close the socket. Timeout just means that the socket did not become readable/writeable/or counter an error in the given time. Just call select again like I suggested in the original answer.

Comment: @SamiSallinen - If I comment out 'm_incompleteConnect = false;' in the check for select == 0 then I never get a connection as the first connect (when server isn't available) never appears to retry?